# how to convert data with unit seconds since specific date in date time format using python

Tags: python, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a netCDF4 with the following time variable:

```
data.variables['TimeDateTime']

<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 TimeDateTime(TimeDateTime)
    _FillValue: nan
    units: seconds since 2018-09-03 10:38:38.034729
    calendar: proleptic_gregorian
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (2554274,)
filling on


data.variables['TimeDateTime'][:]

masked_array(data=[0.0000000e+00, 1.1993774e+01, 2.3987533e+01, ...,
                   3.6024153e+07, 3.6024165e+07, 3.6024177e+07],
             mask=False,
       fill_value=1e+20)
```

I would like to have the time variable in following date time format `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

Can anyone help? I only find solution for the case - seconds since epoch

Comment: If you knew the number of seconds to `2018-09-03 10:38:38.034729` since epoch, could you solve the problem?

Comment: good point! This way I can solve it. Thanks!